Incorporate newsletter form made with an email marketing tool into an Angular application
It's been a while since I haven't been using Angular (feels like ages to be honest), and I now find myself trying to incorporate a code snippet (actually a newsletter form, made with Mailerlite), into an existing Angular application that I developed few years ago.
I was given a pre-generated form which acts as its own working module (with style, content and functionalities), and I am now trying to add it into my website made with Angular. However, I am not sure exactly where to start.
I have generated a new component with the Angular CLI by doing ng generate c newsletter and I have separated the style and html parts into the respective files that were generated by the CLI (newsletter.component.css and newsletter.component.html).
I am not sure now how to handle the <script> tags, especially since they seem to call external js code and has jQuery inside.
I was wondering if I should put this into a service or not, rather than in a component. Moreover, since I will probably put the newsletter form in many pages of my website, I am not sure where to put this code to better make use of it anywhere I want.
Anyway, this is the code I am trying to incorporate (some parts are purposefully obfuscated with XXXXXXX since I am not sure whether they are tied to sensitive functionality or not):
<script>
  function ml_webform_success_XXXXXXX() {
    var $ = ml_jQuery || jQuery;
    $(".ml-subscribe-form-XXXXXXX .row-success").show();
    $(".ml-subscribe-form-XXXXXXX .row-form").hide();
  }
</script>

<script
  src="https://groot.mailerlite.com/js/w/webforms.min.js?XXXXXXX"
  type="text/javascript"
></script>
<script>
  fetch(
    "https://assets.mailerlite.com/jsonp/467137/forms/XXXXXXX/takel"
  );
</script>

